# Ruby regex capture groups in gsub

Tags: ruby, regex, gsub

Say I want to switch each letter in a message with it's place in the reverse alphabet. Why can't I seem to use the captured group and do it in one gsub?

Perhaps someone could explain in general about using captured groups in gsub, can the back references be bare(no ' ')? Can I use #{\1}?

```
def decode(message)
  a = ('a'..'z').to_a
  z = a.reverse
  message.gsub!(/([[:alpha:]])/, z[a.index('\1')]) 
end

decode("the quick brown fox")
```

Comment: The `\1` is not "initialized" here. Use a block,

Comment: Are you just trying to reverse the words in the string or are you specifically searching for capture groups?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Remember that arguments to methods are evaluated immediately and the result of that is passed in to the method. If you want to make the substitution adapt to the match:

```
message.gsub!(/([[:alpha:]])/) { |m| z[a.index($1)] }
```

That employs a block that gets evaluated for each match.

Comment: @tadman, as you know well, you don't need a capture group here. :-)

Answer (score 2):

#### Using `gsub`:

Your code was not working because `'\1'` is not yet being evaluated as its regex match, at the point you desire. This can be solved by using a block, so the match variable is defined:

```
message.gsub(/[[:alpha:]]/) { |char| z[a.index(char)] }
```

#### Using `tr`:

A more efficient way to solve problems like this, where you are simply "replacing one set of characters with another set", is to instead use [`String#tr`](http://apidock.com/ruby/String/tr). This could be done as follows:

```
message.tr(a.join(''), z.join(''))
```

Comment: Tadman's answer uses `gsub!` instead of `gsub`, which is bad practice and bug prone in this context. (You're mutating the original object, and the method may unexpectedly return `nil`.) In addition, that answer uses `$1` instead of the match result, which is also bad practice. (It's not thread safe and uses an unnecessary variable.)

Comment: Yes, your right. I deleted my comment. Somehow I hadn't noticed you used the block variable instead of the value of the capture group, speaking of which, are you sure you want an unused capture group? I'll delete this when you've seen it.

Comment: If you can find a way to achieve this with `gsub` *without* a block, then please share!

Comment: I said the (regex's)  capture group  is not needed.

Comment: Ahhh right, I get what you mean now. Yeah sure, fair enough. Not that it makes much difference. :P I've edited my answer. (Also as I said, I wouldn't even advise using `gsub` for this task anyway!)

Answer (score 0):

One way is to manipulate ASCII values.

```
def code(message)
  message.gsub(/[[:alpha:]]/) { |s| (((s < 'a') ? 155 : 219 ) - s.ord).chr }
end

coded = code("the quick brown fox")
  #=> "gsv jfrxp yildm ulc" 
code(coded)
  #=> "the quick brown fox"
```

Note:

```
'A'.ord + 'Z'.ord
  #=> 155 
'a'.ord + 'z'.ord
  #=> 219
```

Another is to use a hash:

```
a = ('a'..'z').to_a
Ch = a.zip(a.reverse).to_h
  #=> {"a"=>"z", "b"=>"y",..., "y"=>"b", "z"=>"a"} 

def code(message)
  message.gsub(/[[:alpha:]]/, Ch)
end

coded = code("the quick brown fox")
  #=> "gsv jfrxp yildm ulc"
code(coded)
  #=> "the quick brown fox"
```